# Duplicate Array Data Web Scraping

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, web-scraping

I can't seem to get the article duplicates out of my web scraper results, this is my code:

```
app.get("/scrape", function (req, res) {

  request("https://www.nytimes.com/", function (error, response, html) {

    // Load the HTML into cheerio and save it to a variable
    // '$' becomes a shorthand for cheerio's selector commands, much like jQuery's '$'
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var uniqueResults = [];
    // With cheerio, find each p-tag with the "title" class
    // (i: iterator. element: the current element)
    $("div.collection").each(function (i, element) {
      // An empty array to save the data that we'll scrape
      var results = [];
      // store scraped data in appropriate variables

          results.link = $(element).find("a").attr("href");
          results.title = $(element).find("a").text();
          results.summary = $(element).find("p.summary").text().trim();

      // Log the results once you've looped through each of the elements found with cheerio
      db.Article.create(results)
        .then(function (dbArticle) {
          res.json(dbArticle);
        }).catch(function (err) {
          return res.json(err);
        });

    });
    res.send("You scraped the data successfully.");
  });
});

// Route for getting all Articles from the db
app.get("/articles", function (req, res) {
  // Grab every document in the Articles collection
  db.Article.find()
    .then(function (dbArticle) {

      res.json(dbArticle);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      res.json(err);
    });
});
```

Right now I am getting five copies of each article sent to the user. I have tried db.Article.distinct and various versions of this to filter the results down to only unique articles. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

**In Short:**
Switching the `var results = []` from an Array to an Object `var results = {}` did the trick for me. Still haven't figured out the exact reason for the duplicate insertion of documents in database, will update as soon I find out.

**Long Story:**

You have multiple mistakes and points of improvement there in your code. I will try pointing them out:

Let's follow them first to make your code error free.

**Mistakes**

**1.** Although mongoose's *`model.create`*, *`new mongoose()`* does seem to work fine with Arrays but I haven't seen such a use before and it does not even look appropriate.

If you intend to create documents one after another then represent your documents using an object instead of an Array. Using an array is more mainstream when you intend to create multiple documents at once.

So switch -

```
var results = [];
```

to

```
var results = {};
```

**2.** Sending response headers after they are already sent will create for you an error. I don't know if you have already noticed it or not but its pretty much clear upfront as once the error is popped up the remaining documents won't get stored because of `PromiseRejection Error` if you haven't setup a `try/catch` block.

The block inside `$("div.collection").each(function (i, element)` runs asynchronously so your process control won't wait for each document to get processed, instead it would immediately execute `res.send("You scraped the data successfully.");`.

This will effectively terminate the Http connection between the client and the server and any further issue of response termination calls like `res.json(dbArticle)` or `res.json(err)` will throw an error.

So, just comment the `res.json` statements inside the `.create`'s `then` and `catch` methods. This will although terminate the response even before the whole articles are saved in the DB but you need not to worry as your code would still work behind the scene saving articles in database for you (asynchronously).

If you want your response to be terminated only after you have successfully saved the data then change your middleware implementation to -

```
request('https://www.nytimes.com', (err, response, html) => {
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  var results = [];
  $("div.collection").each(function (i, element) {
    var ob = {};
    ob.link = $(element).find("a").attr("href");
    ob.title = $(element).find("a").text();
    ob.summary = $(element).find("p.summary").text().trim();
    results.push(ob);
  });

  db.Article.create(results)
    .then(function (dbArticles) {
      res.json(dbArticles);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      return res.json(err);
    });
});
```

*After making above changes and even after the first one, my version of your code ran fine. So if you want you can continue on with your current version, or you may try reading some points of improvement.*

**Points of Improvements**

**1.** Era of callbacks is long gone:

Convert your implementation to utilise Promises as they are more maintainable and easier to reason about. Here are the things you can do -

Change request library from `request` to [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or any one which supports Promises by default.

**2.** Make effective use of mongoose methods for insertion. You can perform bulk inserts of multiple statements in just one query. You may find [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/) on creating documents in mongodb quite helpful.

**3.** Start using some frontend task automation library such as [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) or [nightmare.js](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) for data scraping related task. Trust me, they make life a hell lot easier than using cheerio or any other library for the same. Their docs are really good and well maintained so you won't have have hard time picking these up.